# angularjs factory internal functions not factory dependend?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, factory, protected

I'm trying to have 2 classes (factorys) in my Module

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory("TPreferences",function($cordovaSQLite){
    _set = function(pName, pValue){
            console.log("Setting: "+pName+":"+pValue);
            }

    _addList = function(pList){
                for(var p=0; p < pList.length; p++)
                {
                    _set(pList[p].name, pList[p].value);
                }
            }


    return {
        init: function(){
                        _addList(gSettings);
        }
    }
})

.factory("TDayList",function($cordovaSQLite){
    _add = function(pName, pValue){
            console.log("Day: "+pName+":"+pValue);
            }

    _addList = function(pList){
        for(var p=0; p < pList.length; p++)
        {
            _add(pList[p].name,pList[p].value);
        }
    }

    return {
        init: function(){
                        _addList(gExampleDays);
                    }
    };

});
```

**Problem**: When calling TPreferences.init(), "Day:..." is logged. 
I assumed that ".factory(...)"-Stuff to be a class, where _addList is a protected function, but it seems that _addList seems to be (at least module-wide) global and is overwritten by the second definition with the same name even though in a different factory.

**Question**: Sure, I could in this example simply change the name of one of the functions, but I would more like to handle a factory like a class, so that I can use names of internal functions twice. So, what would be the smartest way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it seems that _addList seems to be (at least module-wide) global and is overwritten by the second definition

Of course it's global, because you declared it globally. Initializations without declarations become global variables. So never forget declaring your variables properly (`const`, `let`, `var`):

```
const _addList = function(pList) {
  for (var p=0; p < pList.length; p++) {
    _set(pList[p].name, pList[p].value);
  }
}
```

Comment: It can be so easy :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `var` in your factories which makes those functions global. Either use var or if you can use `ES6`, use `let` keyword:

```
.factory("TPreferences",function($cordovaSQLite){
    var _set = function(pName, pValue){
        console.log("Setting: "+pName+":"+pValue);
        }

    var _addList = function(pList){
            for(var p=0; p < pList.length; p++)
            {
                _set(pList[p].name, pList[p].value);
            }
        }


    return {
        init: function(){
                    _addList(gSettings);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: It can be so easy :) Thanks a lot